# SQL Server Reversed CONTAINS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm not sure if this even possible and I'm totally not sure how to ask this question properly, but I'll give it a try.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and there is a database-column which contains the value "1000". 
Now I'll get the following value from an interface: "100023".

Now I want to write a SQL Server query where I can use the `100023` and find the row which which contains the 1000. Therefore, I don't want to use `CONTAINS` with the 1000 to find 100023, but the other way around. I want to do this, because the interface also return values like 100024, 100025, 100025, but I always just want to have the row which contains the 1000. I sadly can't change the return values from the interface and cut the last two digits off.

I'm not sure, if this makes even sense logically, but maybe someone can help me with that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So the parameter is `100023` (varchar) and you want to find all records which are _substrings_?

Comment: How are you calling the query? If you can execute an arbitrary query why can't you cut the two characters off then?

Comment: I sense a contradiction.  Values 100024 and 100025 contain 1000 but you say you don't want them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `LIKE`:

```
DECLARE @param varchar(10)
SET @param = '100023'

SELECT Value 
FROM dbo.TableName 
WHERE @param LIKE '%' + Value + '%'
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0198/1/0)</kbd>

Comment: Since the value starts with `1000` won't `LIKE Value + '%'` be more accurate?

Comment: @EvertonAgner: but he wants the "opoosite" of [`CONTAINS`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) and also mentioned: _"row which **contains** the 1000"_ not _row which **starts with** 1000_.

Comment: As far as I understood the problem, he wants to query for either `100023`, `100024`, `100025` etc. and always find `1000`.

Comment: @EvertonAgner: If you look the [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0198/9/0) you'll see that he always find 1000.

Comment: Okay, but it's finding `1000` if you query for `999100023`, for instance. Anyways, the OP must check if is that what he wants... This statement is what bugged me: `I sadly can't change the return values from the interface and cut the last two digits off`

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention, that it not necessarily has to an int and the number of following characters is variable (it can be more or less than two), it also could be a string like '1000A237K', but I tested it with your solution and it seems to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your requirement correctly. The following query will get the rows you're looking for without actually altering the input parameter ( Well, without persisting any alteration to the input parameter. ) If you are able to make the alteration in a previous operation before the query you will get the full benefit of a sargable equality clause and therefore a nice index seek.

```
DECLARE @param varchar(10)
SET @param = '100023'


declare @testTable table(num int, described_as varchar(100))

insert into @testTable values 
( 1000, 'The number one thousand'),
( 2000, 'The number two thousand')

SELECT *
FROM @testTable 
WHERE num = FLOOR( ROUND(@param, -2)) / 100
```

If not, please try and rephrase your text so the community can better understand your requirements. :)